# How can I make my increment or Swift 3 Friendly?

Tags: swift, swift3

```
static func randomShape() -> Shape {
    // Find out count of possible shapes
    var maxValue = 0
    while let _ = self.init(rawValue: ++maxValue) {}
    // Generate random number from number of shapes
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maxValue)))
    // Create and return shape
    let shape = self.init(rawValue: randomNumber)!

    return shape
}
```

Focus on the `while let _ = self.init(rawValue: ++maxValue) {}`

I et the Error that `++` has been deprecated from Swift, However I don't know how i can change my method to still function right.

I tried MaxValue += 1 and i get the error

```
'+=' produces '()', not the expected contextual result type 'Int'
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
++value
```

Basically increments the value first and then uses the new value.

So this...

```
someFunc(++value)
```

Is the same as doing...

```
value += 1
someFunc(value)
```

Answer (score 3):

@Chris Karani you can use Xcode to fix this kind of issues. Try to use Xcode's red error dots at left of your editor. For instance :

[image]

if you will click on "fix-it" it'll handle all for you.

[image]

Also you can use "Edit/Convert/To Current Swift Syntax" menu for converting all your project to Swift 3 syntax. Make sure you select your main target from "Select targets to convert" screen.

Your answer is :

```
maxValue += 1
```

Comment: Does this work when ++ is used inside a function parameter? It would have to pull the increment out onto the previous line. Cool if it does :-)

Comment: OK, I just tested this. When it's on a line on its own (like your example) Xcode will auto fix it. But when it's used inside a function call (like the OP) then Xcode just flags it as an error and doesn't offer auto fix.